# Adding a field Columns in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to create a SharePoint list.

There are two fields units and descriptions. Unit and description (number and single line of text, min. 1 and max. 15). When I click on + button/ add button new column with unit1 and description1 need to be in the form.

Please let me know if this is possible.If not, please suggest something similar

Answer (score 0):

In list settings:

- Unit: Column type Number. Set Min as 1 and Max as 15. Set decimal places to 0 if you want integers.
- Description: Single line of text. You can set default text.

To be clear though, the way your question is worded is not so clear. When you Add a new item you will add a row (not a column). The columns are the data fields you have added. This is a small semantic, and may be down to perhaps English not being your first language.

I would suggest you look at some online training for SharePoint. I can see you are a new contributor. And that the question you are asking shows how new you are to the SharePoint platform and to this site. Stack Overflow is not a training site. Rather, it's a research hub, and if you really can't find an answer to your question, then a well thought through question is worth asking.

Finally, you will likely find this site more suitable for this kind of question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/